# Trying to download images using gem image_dowloader

Tags: ruby, download, rubygems

This is what i have so far.
Its using the gem image_downloader

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'image_downloader'

downloader = ImageDownloader::Process.new('www.test.com','img_dir/')
downloader.parse(:any_looks_like_image => true)
downloader.download()
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Oh forgot to add part. Well i want to download images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageDownloader::Process.new method second argument should be your local machine target path:

Your code Before:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'image_downloader'

downloader = ImageDownloader::Process.new('www.test.com','img_dir/')
downloader.parse(:any_looks_like_image => true)
downloader.download()
```

After:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'image_downloader'
require 'open-uri'

downloader = ImageDownloader::Process.new('<page url>','<your local directory complete path(target to place all images)>')
downloader.parse(:any_looks_like_image => true)
downloader.download()
```

Comment: Thanks that works. but now the images are just saying this file format is not supported